# No module named RPA error even after successfully importing RPA package

Tags: python, rpa

I am getting no module named RPA error, even after successfully importing RPA.

[image: Please check this image for details]

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73918994/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution shown was to re-install RPA with `pip install rpa`.
The problem kept the same. What worked was installing the RPA framework:
`pip install rpaframework`.